# WsusContent folder how to clear down

Tags: wsus, patch-management

I have an SBS2008 server, the WsusContent folder was 78 GB in size, I have ran the server cleanup wizard but it is still 71GB, is there any safe way to clear these out, there are a total of 7786 updates,  there are only 7 PCs in the network so it seems like a huge amount of data for such a small network of PCs, there are also a lot of security updates for older software like office 2002 and XP are these updates required these are marked as 100% and installed, all the PCs are windows 7? if so would the only option be upgrading the hard disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This TechNet blog should help you out:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/gborger/archive/2009/02/27/what-to-do-when-your-wsuscontent-folder-grows-too-large.aspx